# how to get go func argument value and set value by ebpf?

Tags: go, ebpf

env: go 1.18.1,

I have two programs, tracee.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//go:noinline
func simpleFunction(val int) {
    fmt.Println("item value:", val)
}

func main() {
    simpleFunction(100)
}
```

the other tracer.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

var eBPF_Text = `
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(events);

inline int function_was_called(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
   void* stackAddr = (void*)ctx->sp;
   long parameter_value;
   bpf_probe_read(&parameter_value, sizeof(parameter_value), stackAddr+8);

   long tmp = 520;
   bpf_probe_write_user(stackAddr+8, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));

   events.perf_submit(ctx, &parameter_value, sizeof(parameter_value));
   return 0;
}
`
var tracePrg string
var traceFun string

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&tracePrg, "binary", "", "")
    flag.StringVar(&traceFun, "func", "", "The function to probe")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    bpfModule := bcc.NewModule(eBPF_Text, []string{})
    uprobeFd, err := bpfModule.LoadUprobe("function_was_called")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err = bpfModule.AttachUprobe(tracePrg,
        traceFun, uprobeFd, -1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    table := bcc.NewTable(bpfModule.TableId("events"), bpfModule)

    outputChannel := make(chan []byte)
    lostChan := make(chan uint64)

    perfMap, err := bcc.InitPerfMap(table, outputChannel, lostChan)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    sigCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigCh, os.Interrupt)

    go func() {
        for {
            value := <-outputChannel
            var item int64
            if err = binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(value),
                binary.LittleEndian, &item); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(item)
        }
    }()
    perfMap.Start()
    <-sigCh
    perfMap.Stop()
}
```

My intention is to capture the value of the simpleFunction func and set it to 520

when i started ebpf program,

```bash
./tracer --binary ./tracee  --func main.simpleFunction
```

then run ./tracee

[image]
[image]

as the turns out, the value doesn't change to  520. What is the captured result  824633729440?

what did I do wrong? and what should i do?